# What does regclass mean in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I have the following line in a CREATE TABLE statement:

```
field1_id bigint DEFAULT nextval('table1_field1_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
```

What does regclass mean in the above? Is it an absolute requirement to add `::regclass`?

**N.B:** I had seen the Postgresql documentation [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) which tells about `regclass`, but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, you do not need the cast to `regclass` when calling a function like `nextval` that accepts a `regclass` parameter, as there is an implict cast from `text` to `regclass`. In some other contexts an explicit cast to `regclass` may be required.

**Explanation:**

`::regclass` is a cast, like `::integer`.

`regclass` is a "magic" data type; it's actually an alias for `oid`, or "object identifier". See [Object identifier types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) in the documentation. Casting to `regclass` is a shortcut way of saying "this the name of a relation, please convert it to the oid of that relation". Casts to `regclass` are aware of the `search_path`, unlike querying `pg_class` for a relation's `oid` directly, so casting to regclass isn't exactly equivalent to subquerying `pg_class`.

Tables are relations. So are sequences, and views. So you can get the oid of a view or sequence by casting to regclass too.

There are implicit casts defined for `text` to `regclass`, so if you omit the explicit cast and you're calling a function that accepts `regclass` the cast is done automatically. So you do *not* need it in, for example, `nextval` calls.

There are other places where you may. For example you can't compare `text` directly with `oid`; so you can do this:

```
regress=> select * from pg_class where oid = 'table1'::regclass;
```

but not this:

```
regress=> select * from pg_class where oid = 'table1';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type oid: "table1"
LINE 1: select * from pg_class where oid = 'table1';
```

---

Just for fun I tried to write a query that performed the equivalent operation of casting to `regclass`. Don't use it, it's mostly for fun, and as an attempt to demo what's actually happening. Unless you're really interested in how Pg's guts work you can stop reading here.

As I understand it, `'sequence_name'::regclass::oid` is roughly equivalent to the following query:

```
WITH sp(sp_ord, sp_schema) AS (
  SELECT 
    generate_series(1, array_length(current_schemas('t'),1)),
    unnest(current_schemas('t'))
)
SELECT c.oid
FROM pg_class c INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
INNER JOIN sp ON (n.nspname = sp.sp_schema)
WHERE c.relname = 'sequence_name'
ORDER BY sp.sp_ord
LIMIT 1;
```

except that it's a lot shorter and a lot faster. See [System information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) for the definition of `current_schemas(...)`, etc.

In other words:

- Get a ab array listing all schemas we have access to and pair each entry up with an ordinal number for its position in the array
- Search `pg_class` for relations with matching names and associate each with its namespace (schema)
- Sort the list of remaining relations by the order in which their schemas appeared in `search_path`
- and pick the first match

Comment: So my query line would essentially be interpreted as `nextval(oid1)`, where `oid1` is the `oid` of `table1_field1_id_seq`. Am I right?

Comment: @saji89 Correct, but note that the cast to oid is resolved when the query is executed, not when the table is defined. This matters because if you were to drop and re-create the sequence it'd have a new oid, but the same name. The cast to oid will find the new oid.

Comment: So even if I drop a sequence, the oid of that sequence is still there in the system?

Comment: @saji89 The row with that oid is removed from `pg_class`, where information about sequences, tables and views is kept. However, oids aren't re-used so a new oid is allocated when you create a new sequence, even if it has the same name. Try it. `CREATE SEQUENCE s1; SELECT 's1'::regclass::oid; DROP SEQUENCE s1; CREATE SEQUENCE s1; SELECT 's1'::regclass::oid;`. You'll get two different oids. If you `select * from pg_class where oid = 28327` (or whatever the first oid was) after dropping the sequence, you'll get no results because that row is gone from `pg_class`.

Comment: +1, Now its fully clear. Thanks for that clarification and your time.. And bearing with me.. ;)

Comment: Oops, the latest update did confuse me :`'sequence_name'::regclass::oid`. in that `'sequence_name'::regclass` already is translated to oid isn't it? Then what does the last `::oid` mean?

Comment: @saji89 Sorry, should've explained. While `regclass` is an oid internally, it's still *displayed* as a table name in `psql` output, etc. If you want to display the actual `oid`, you can cast to `oid`, which is what `'sequence_name'::regclass::oid` does; casts to `regclass` then casts that to `oid` so it isn't formatted for display anymore. As I said, `regclass` is kind of a magic type.

Comment: As a bonus, you can also cast _from_ the numerical oid, i.e. `select 1234::regclass`, which can be useful if you want to know 'what table a particular `pg_toast_` table is associated with.

Comment: `'table'::regclass` and `'table'::regtype` return the same output apart from the data type. Does that mean that every table is a "class" and a "data type" in the eyes of Postgres?

Comment: @Rafs Correct. Each table is also a type in postgres and that type has an internal numeric object-id (oid).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the documentation, oid are subdivided in types. `regclass` are database objects representing relations (so that they belong to the metadata table pg_class).

It expresses a dependency between the sequence and the `DEFAULT` expression (meaning the process of producing a default value if no explicit value is provided in a INSERT query for instance),  so that if one emits a `DROP SEQUENCE ...` on the sequence, the query won't pass, unless it's cascaded (by writing `DROP SEQUENCE table1_field1_id_seq CASCADE`).

Comment: So, If I cascade the `DROP SEQUENCE`, the column(field) where I had used this sequence as `DEFAULT` will have that default value removed?

Comment: I think so. It's what I understand from the documentation, but I didn't test it.

Comment: I think that the cast to that type of oid enforces the dependency relationship between the expression and the sequence, so that removing it from the definition would remove de dependency, and let you drop the sequence without cascading, but again you should test to confirm that.

Comment: @Craig Ringer said that when the type is not explicit, the type casting is resolved at query execution time, and then it infers the relationship *from* the default expression *to* the sequence, but I don't think that the engine will check dynamically if expressions are tied to the sequence (relationship *from* the sequence *to* another object), and having that `regclass` tells the engine that a relationship exists.