# Postgres return a default value when a column doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a query where I essentially want a fallback value if a certain column is missing. I was wondering if I can handle this purely in my query (rather than probing first and sending a seperate query. In essence i'm looking for an equivalent to `COALESCE` that handles the case of a missing column.

Imagine the following 2 tables.

```
T1
id | title | extra
1    A     | value

- and -

T2
id | title
1    A
```

I'd like to be able to SELECT from either of these tables WITH THE SAME QUERY.

eg, if t2 actually had an 'extra' column I could use

```
 SELECT id,title, COALESCE(extra, 'default') as extra
```

But that only works if the column value is NULL, not when the column is missing entirely.

I would prefer an SQL version but I can accept a PLPGSQL function (with a behaviour similiar to COALLESCE) too.

*NOTE to SQL purists: I don't really feel like debating why I want to do this in SQL and not in application logic (or why I won't just add the column permanently to the schema) so please restrict your comments/answers to the specific request and not your opinion on database 'correctness' or whatever else might offend you about this question.*

Comment: Does the plpgsql tag suggest that you'd be happy to use a function instead of the table?

Comment: I mean I would accept a function that works like COALESCE but for missing fields, not NULLS.

Comment: @mu. Thanks, that makes sense though I have had success with similiar 'subselect' functions provided I pass the table name as a 'regclass' argument to the function, `SELECT myFunc('mytable','mycol','mydefaultvalue') AS extra` should work when the function is defined as `myFunc(IN _tbl regclass, IN _col regclass, IN default text)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to look up the information schema table and do a little magic with it.

Something like:

```
SELECT id, title, CASE WHEN extra_exists THEN extra ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='mytable' AND column_name='extra') AS extra_exists) extra
```

Edit: Where 'mytable' needs to be passed in for the table you want to query.

Comment: ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented
LINE 1: ...id, title, CASE WHEN extra_exists THEN extra ELSE 'default' ... (Postgres 8.4)

Comment: Looks like you need to cast as well, this change works: `THEN "extra"::text ELSE 'default'::text`

Comment: +1 Didn't know that PostgreSQL so tolerant. SQL will raise an error if I'll try to do query like that. Here's SQL fiddle to see it's working BTW - http://sqlfiddle.com/index.cfm?_escaped_fragment_=2/d41d8/9720#!12/67d69/1

Comment: The reason why this hack happens to work is not disclosed, which makes it *dangerous and possibly very annoying*. It also does not work at all without the explicit cast like SpliFF mentions.

Comment: @RomanPekar: Postgres is *not* as tolerant as this answer makes it seem. I added an explanation.

Answer (score 22):

#### Why does [Rowan's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951791/939860) work (mostly)?

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN extra_exists THEN extra::text ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM   tbl
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM information_schema.columns 
      WHERE  table_name = 'tbl'
      AND    column_name = 'extra')
   ) AS extra(extra_exists)
```

Normally, it would not work at all. Postgres parses the SQL statement and throws an exception if *any* of the involved columns does not exist.

The trick is to introduce a table name (or alias) with the same name as the column name in question. `extra` in this case. Every table name can be referenced as a whole, which results in the whole row being returned as type `record`. And since every type can be cast to `text`, we can cast this whole record to `text`. This way, Postgres accepts the query as valid.

Since column names take precedence over table names, `extra::text` is interpreted to be the column `tbl.extra` if the column exists. Otherwise, it would default to returning the whole row of the table `extra` - which never happens.

Try to pick a different table alias for `extra` to see for yourself.

This is an **undocumented hack and might break** if Postgres decides to change the way SQL strings are parsed and planned in future versions - even though unlikely.

#### Unambiguous

**If** you decide to use this, at least **make it unambiguous**.

A table name alone is not unique. A table named "tbl" can exist any number of times in multiple schemas of the same database, which could lead to very confusing and completely false results. You *need* to supply the schema name additionally:

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN col_exists THEN extra::text ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM   tbl
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM information_schema.columns 
      WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
      AND    table_name = 'tbl'
      AND    column_name = 'extra'
      ) AS col_exists
   ) extra;
```

#### Faster

Since this query is hardly portable to other RDBMS, I suggest to use the [**catalog table `pg_attribute`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) instead of the information schema view `information_schema.columns`. About 10 times faster.

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN col_exists THEN extra::text ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM   tbl
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = 'myschema.tbl'::regclass  -- schema-qualified!
      AND    attname  = 'extra'
      AND    NOT attisdropped    -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum   > 0        -- no system columns
      )
   ) extra(col_exists);
```

Also using the **more convenient and secure cast to `regclass`**. See:

- [What does regclass mean in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289107/what-does-regclass-signify-in-postgresql/13290020#13290020)

You can attach the needed alias to fool Postgres to *any* table, including the primary table itself. You don't need to join to another relation at all, which should be fastest:

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                         WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
                         AND    attname  = 'extra'
                         AND    NOT attisdropped
                         AND    attnum   > 0)
            THEN extra::text
            ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM tbl AS extra;
```

#### Convenience

You could encapsulate the test for existence in a simple SQL function (once), arriving (almost) at the function you have been asking for:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION col_exists(_tbl regclass, _col text)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = $1
   AND    attname  = $2
   AND    NOT attisdropped
   AND    attnum   > 0
   )
$func$;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION col_exists(regclass, text) IS
'Test for existence of a column. Returns TRUE / FALSE.
$1 .. exact table name (case sensitive!), optionally schema-qualified
$2 .. exact column name (case sensitive!)';
```

Simplifies the query to:

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN col_exists THEN extra::text ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM   tbl
CROSS  JOIN col_exists('tbl', 'extra') AS extra(col_exists);
```

Using the form with additional relation here, since it turned out to be faster with the function.

Still, you only get the **text representation** of the column with any of these queries. It's not as simple to get the **actual type**.

### Benchmark

I ran a quick benchmark with 100k rows on pg 9.1 and 9.2 to find these to be fastest:

Fastest:

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                         WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
                         AND    attname  = 'extra'
                         AND    NOT attisdropped
                         AND    attnum   > 0)
            THEN extra::text
            ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM   tbl AS extra;
```

2nd fastest:

```sql
SELECT id, title
     , CASE WHEN col_exists THEN extra::text ELSE 'default' END AS extra
FROM   tbl
CROSS  JOIN col_exists('tbl', 'extra') AS extra(col_exists);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=869840a379a404e0b0d126d1082b5ccc)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dc1c2/5)</sub>

Comment: +1 @ErwinBrandstetter great as always, I had no time at work to look closer at the query to understand why it works, and totally forgot about this question when I came home, thanks for explanation

Comment: Great explanation, I leant something.

Comment: Excellent details. I didn't even understand why you were calling it a hack until you explained the column vs. table thing. Luckily for me I have no need for SQL compliance with other DBMS and I can pick and choose my Postgres version so all of your methods/info are useful.